# How do I calculate the circumference of a n-sphere?

Tags: geometry, spheres, 4-manifolds

I have a 4-dimensional sphere of radius r. From it, I can calculate the 3-dimensional surface area of the hypersphere using the formula 2pi^2r^3. I now need to calculate it's circumference, but I'm not allowed to use the radius, I have to use the surface area, which is, however, a 3d object, so I don't know which formula to use.

Comment: How do you define the circumference?

Comment: Just 2 pi r, which will get me the circumference of a plane inside the sphere. I just don't know how to get it from the 3d surface of a 4d sphere, if I could get it from the radius directly, it would sill be the same formula.